# Get exit code of command prior to Perl invocation

Tags: linux, bash, perl

How do I inside Perl get the exit code of the command run prior to the Perl invocation?

```
$ ls asdf
ls: asdf: No such file or directory
$ perl -le 'print $?'
0
```

I want it to return 2 (exit status of `ls`).

```
$ ls asdf
ls: asdf: No such file or directory
$ perl -le 'print $ENV{"?"}'
```

Returns blank line.

```
$ ls asdf
ls: asdf: No such file or directory
$ perl -le "print $?"
2
```

Using shell interpolation I can get my result. But this is not what I want since I need the exit code in a stand alone Perl script.

Comment: `$?` is not exported to the environment. I don't know that you can do this.

Comment: Solutions sofar add the exit status as an argument to the Perl invocation, but this requires a wrapper script. Wouldn't it be possible inside Perl get the PID, then the parent PID for the shell, then the exit status from some internal data structure. I am ready to do ugly stuff.

Comment: I **highly** doubt it is stored anywhere you can reliably access in the shell process. It is almost certainly just stored inside some variable somewhere internally. Your best bet for this is likely to be to move the command *into* the perl script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
xxx; perl -le 'print $ARGV[0]' $?
```

or

```
xxx; perl -le 'print '"$?"''
```

but the latter one depends too much of the SHELL you are using and should be avoided

Comment: Grab that puppy one way or another :-)

Comment: Nice, but I need this packed into a Perl script like `xxx; my_cmd.pl`. I guess I could make a shell wrapper around my Perl script which add `$?` as argument.

Comment: @Axel Bregnsbo, Do you realize that anything you pass to `-e` can be placed in a script? If so, what's the problem with `xxx; my_cmd.pl $?`?

Comment: @ikegami No much wrong with `my_cmd.pl $?` except for a descrease in usability. My script is a sms utility which you can call after running some command taking hours/days execution time, e.g. `big_job; sms.pl +4512131415 "job is done"`. I wanted the message to be prefixed with 'ok' or 'error' depending on the exit status. I guess the user just have to do: `sms.pl +4512131415 "$? job is done"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ ls asdf
$ EC=$? perl -le 'print $ENV{"EC"}'
```

`perl -le 'print $?'` doesn't work because there is no relation between $? in your shell and the one in Perl - Perl just re-used the name for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

`$?` is not a true environment variable.

```
$ export '?'
-bash: export: `?': not a valid identifier
```

That means you'll need to explicitly pass it to the script. The two safe and easy ways are

```
perl -E'say $ARGV[0]' $?
```

and

```
EC=$? perl -E'say $ENV{EC}'
```

But I understand you'd rather not have to specify `$?`. If that's so, then what you should do is have the previous command executed by your script instead of having it executed before your script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# usage: wrapper program [arg [...]]
use feature qw( say );
system { $ARGV[0] } @ARGV;
say $? & 0x7F ? 0x80 | ($? & 0x7F) : $? >> 8;
```

```
$ true

$ echo $?
0

$ wrapper true
0
```

```
$ false

$ echo $?
1

$ wrapper false
1
```

```
$ perl -e'kill INT => $$'

$ echo $?
130

$ wrapper perl -e'kill INT => $$'
130
```

Answer (score 0):

> My script is a sms utility which you can call after running some command taking hours/days execution time, e.g. `big_job; sms.pl +4512131415 "job is done"`. I wanted the message to be prefixed with 'ok' or 'error' depending on the exit status.

```
# usage: notify bigjob [arg [...]]

phone="+4512131415"

if "$@" ; then
   sms.pl "$phone" "job succeeded"
else
   sms.pl "$phone" "job failed"
fi
```

Comment: Not able to put a wrapper around `big_job` as it is just a place holder for any kind of large job invocation.

Comment: That's what arguments and variables are for.

Comment: In the most often use-case I call `sms.pl` *after* I have started my `big_job`. E.g. `big_job` (then realizing I want a notification) at which point I do `ctrl-z fg; sms.pl +4512131415 "job done"<enter>`

Comment: Then you have to pass the exit code as I explained in my earlier answer. Things can't magically happen on their own.